# React native Code push is not updating app to the latest pushed version

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I have updated my **react native app** through **code push** and expected to get all the versions updated to the latest version.

I have used following code for pushing my update

```
code-push release-react <MY-App-Name> android --targetBinaryVersion *
```

Which is supposed to update all the versions to version `1.0.20`; but unfortunately the app is **crashing**.

I have tried disabling all the versions from my **`AppCenter Distribute->Code push`** except the latest version yet it is not working;

I need to know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried setting mandatory option...?

Comment: Yes I have tried mandatory option, yet it showed same result